# Using iScroll with Jquery Mobile.

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I have a simple dialog box created with html5 and Jquery Mobile. It is as follows:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="page2" data-theme="a">

            <div data-role="header" class="header">

                <h1>Door Styles</h1>

            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">


            <div id="wrapper">

                <div id="scroller" class="scroll">  

                    <ul data-role="listview" id="mylist">

                    </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" class="footermodal">

                <h1>↕ Please Scroll ↕</h1>

            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div>
```

The reason I implemented iScroll was because in Android 2.2.2 the dialog box wasn't scrollable. However when I implement it moves my header and footer offscreen almost. And when you scroll, as soon as you let go of it it bounces back to the top. I implement it using this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}

    window.addEventListener('load', setTimeout(function () { loaded(); }, 200), false); 

            </script>
```

It seems to be a conflict between Jquery styling and iScroll styling. Has anyone else had this problem? Or know how to fix it?

Comment: similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512879/touchmove-and-scrollable-content-using-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap-in-android/12532548#12532548

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the element after it is created.

```
newElement =  function () {$ ("body"). append ('<div id='wrapper'> content </ div> ");loaded(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#wrapper { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; }`

I just met this problem and fixed it, make sure your wrapper div's position is absolute or fixed, and top and bottom are defined.