# Touchmove and scrollable content using Jquery Mobile and Phonegap in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Ok so I found that using Jquery Mobile and Phonegap to develop android App works fine in android 4+, but on older versions for example 2.2.2 the scrollable functionality breaks. So I tried to use iScroll, but there were conflicting issues, eventually I just decided to write a Javascript function to handle it. It used to work but now its broken.

SO here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

<head>

<title>Cordova</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>


            <style>
            .scrollstyle{
            height: 320px;
            }
            </style>


            <script type="text/javascript">

             document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkVersion, false);

                function checkVersion() {

                    var droidversion = device.version;

                    myversion = droidversion.substr(0,1);

                    alert(myversion);

                    if ( parseInt(myversion) < 3 ) {
                        alert("do the scroll");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var startY = 0;
                            //var startX = 0;
                            var b = document.body;
                            b.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
                                startY = event.targetTouches[0].screenY;
                                //startX = event.targetTouches[0].screenX;
                            });

                            b.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var posy = event.targetTouches[0].screenY;
                                var h = parent.document.getElementById("scrolldroid");
                                var sty = h.scrollTop;

                                //var posx = event.targetTouches[0].screenX;
                                //var stx = h.scrollLeft;
                                h.scrollTop = sty - (posy - startY);
                                //h.scrollLeft = stx - (posx - startX);
                                startY = posy;
                                //startX = posx;
                            });
                        }, 1000);

                    } else {
                        alert("havent done it!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }


            </script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
            <div data-role="dialog" id="main" data-theme="a">

                <div data-role="header" class="header">

                    <h1>Styles</h1>

                </div><!-- /header -->

                    <div data-role="content" data-them="a">

                        <div id="scrolldroid" class="scrollstyle">


                                <ul data-role="listview">     
                                    <li>OK, that works, but why is the scrollbar</li>
                                    <li> scrolled down to the bottom of the dialog </li>
                                    <li>fsgsgestcontent, and not at the </li>
                                    <li>Line4</li>
                                    <li>Line5</li>
                                    <li>Line6</li>
                                    <li>Line7</li>
                                    <li>Line8</li>
                                    <li>Line9</li>
                                    <li>Line10</li>
                                    <li>Line11</li>
                                    <li>Line12</li>
                                    <li>Line13</li>
                                    <li>Line14</li>
                                    <li>Line15</li>
                                    <li>Line16</li>
                                    <li>Line17</li>
                                    <li>Line18</li>
                                    <li>Line19</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                    <li>fsgsgesthsdgfeagsdgsdgwe4ghesgaegeg</li>
                                </ul>

                        </div>   

                    </div><!-- /content -->

                <div data-role="footer" class="footermodal">
                    <h1>footer</h1>

                </div><!-- /footer -->

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm still a junior developer so my code isn't perfect, sorry. But It should work, in Android 3+ it doesn't execute the function, because the scrolling already works. In Android 2.9.9 or less it does. And it should make the div scrollable, but it doesn't, it used to but then I broke it somehow and I can't figure out how. If anyone knows or can see where Its broken I will love you forever for telling me. Thanks.

**Edit** I also keep getting a yellow error in Eclipse LogCat stating: "Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down"

Answer (score 0):

try to replace :

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="main" data-theme="a">
```

by

```
<div data-role="page" id="main" data-theme="a">
```

and remove the div with id **scrolldroid**

```
<div id="scrolldroid" class="scrollstyle"> </div>
```

and replace :

```
<div data-role="footer" class="footermodal">
```

by

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```