# scrolling a particular Div in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: list, jquery-mobile, scroll

I have been implementing the lists in jquery mobile.when i scroll the list,the page header is also scrolled.Is there any way to scroll only a particular div on touch event without scrolling all the div's in a page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512879/touchmove-and-scrollable-content-using-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap-in-android/12532548#12532548

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your header to remain fixed, then you can apply the data-position="fixed" attribute to it.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

that will prevent it scrolling off the top as you scroll the page.